# How to fix an "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package" error on this module import?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import

I'm importing into **main**.py module, some Python classes which are at the same level and even in the same package of the **main**.py, but it appears an error in the line of the import that says "Attempted relative import beyond top-level package".

The problem is that, when I run the program it works fine, but when I try to debug, it appears: "Exception has ocurred: ImportError attempted relative import with no known parent package" on this line and the program is interrupted.

This is for a personal Python CLI program

```
from .hotspots import GitCommand, IOFunctions,Formatting
```

This is my tree explorer:

```
cli_hotspots
├───.vscode
├───cli_hotspots
│   └───__pycache__
|   └───__main.py
|   └───hotspots.py
```

I hope you will help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who had this problem, I solved it by setting the python configuration entry as a module:

```
{
    "name": "Module: Main.py",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "cli_hotspots.main",
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.